# Stackdriver monitoring metric for error reporting occurence?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver

We are sending exceptions and other errors to stackdriver error reporting, this works well for us.

However, we want to see the error counts for each product as seen on https://console.cloud.google.com/errors (occurrence column) as a metric in stackdiver monitoring for better integration with our ops team. The current notification support is very limited.

Is there a way to have each error occurrence increase a counter metric in monitoring?

Many thanks

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver allows you to use logging entries as a metric. This means that, if you are logging your exceptions, you can use a filter to fetch them and use them as a count metric, this is, number of times the exception was logged.

For that, you need to use [Log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics#creating_a_counter_metric). Once you create the [advanced log query](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) for your exceptions and its respective metric, it will appear in Stackdriver Monitoring.

Depending on under which resource you created your metric (be it, `gce_instance`, `gae_app`, `gke_container`), in Stackdriver Monitoring, you will see it with the `user/*` prefix.

You can use [Metrics Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-explorer) to locate your new metric just by typing `user/` in the search box + the name of your custom log-based metric.

Comment: I don't think that's really an answer. It's a workaround. But I need to have custom alerting policies for errors reported through the error reporting API. There might not even be log messages as I might be publishing directly to that API.  It's insane to me that Google Error reporting in StackDriver doesn't have a metric that can be used in monitoring!  How useless is that!